# redirection depending on mysql value

Tags: php, mysql

in mysql I have attendance1 and attendance2 fields. Both can either have value 'yes' or 'no'. If attendance1 is empty then attendance2 will not be and if attendance2 is empty attendance1 will not be. If attendance1 is empty i want it to go to attendance2.

Comment: insert full url in header function.
`header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

Answer (score 0):

If you put exit, it will end the execution there itself. So use break instead of exit to achieve the result.

Comment: In each case, you are using "exit", but you have to use "break". Because if you use exit, it will stop the whole execution of the php script. But break will just break the current switch statement.

Comment: ok please have a look above i think i have done it right but it is not loading anything